# Pandas function issues - equation output incorrect

Tags: pandas, function, lambda, apply

row['conus_days']>0 or row['conus_days1']>0:
            return row ['conus_days']* 8 + row['conus_days1']*12
        elif (row['Country']== 'Afghanistan' or row['Country']== 'Iraq' or row['Country']=='Somalia' or row['Country']=='Yemen') and row['oconus_days']>0 or row['oconus_days1']>0:
            return row ['oconus_days']* 12 + row['oconus_days1']*8
        elif (row['Country']== 'Afghanistan' or row['Country']== 'Iraq' or row['Country']=='Somalia' or row['Country']=='Yemen'):
            return row ['days_in_month']*12
        elif (row['Country'] == 'Germany') and row['conus_days']>0:
            return row['conus_days']*8 + row['conus_days1']*10
        elif (row['Country'] == 'Germany'):
             return row['days_in_month']* 10
        elif row['Country'] == 'Conus':
            return row['working_days']* 8
        else:
            return row['working_days']*8
    forecast ['hours']= forecast.apply(lambda row: get_hours(row), axis=1)
    print(forecast.head())

this is returning the following output:

```
          Name      EID  Start Date   End Date      Country  year  Month  \
0        xx       123456 2019-08-01 2020-01-03  Afghanistan  2020      1   
1        XX      3456789 2019-09-22 2020-02-16        Conus  2020      1   
2        xx.      456789 2019-12-05 2020-03-12        Conus  2020      1   
3        DR.      789456 2019-09-11 2020-03-04         Iraq  2020      1   
4        JR.      985756 2020-01-03 2020-05-06      Germany  2020      1   

   days_in_month start_month  end_month  working_days  conus_mth  oconus_mth  \
0             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          8           1   
1             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          9           2   
2             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21         12           3   
3             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          9           3   
4             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          1           5   

   conus_days  conus_days1  oconus_days  oconus_days1  hours  
0           0            0            2            25    224  
1           0            0            0             0    168  
2           0            0            0             0    168  
3           0            0            0             0    372  
4           1           28            0             0    344
```

---output on row 4 is incorrect, this should return 288

Comment: Can you post the input data (as text)? That would make it much easier to look for issues & provide you a solution. Also, which value in your output should be 288?

Comment: Moys- the input is the output minus the "hours" column", the last row should return 288, the country == Germany and conus_days>0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing each if statement in double parenthesis allows for each if statement to run individual and accurately.

def get_hours(row):
    if ((row['Country']== 'Afghanistan' or row['Country']== 'Iraq' or row['Country']=='Somalia' or row['Country']=='Yemen') and (row['conus_days']>0 or row['conus_days1']>0)):
        return row ['conus_days']* 8 + row['conus_days1']*12
    if ((row['Country']== 'Afghanistan' or row['Country']== 'Iraq' or row['Country']=='Somalia' or row['Country']=='Yemen') and row['oconus_days']>0 or row['oconus_days1']>0):
        return row ['oconus_days']* 12 + row['oconus_days1']*8
    if (row['Country']== 'Afghanistan' or row['Country']== 'Iraq' or row['Country']=='Somalia' or row['Country']=='Yemen'):
        return row ['days_in_month']*12
    if ((row['Country'] == 'Germany') and row['conus_days']>0):
        return row['conus_days']*8 + row['conus_days1']*10
    if ((row['Country'] == 'Germany') and row['oconus_days']>0):
        return row['oconus_days']*10 + row['oconus_days1']*8
    if (row['Country'] == 'Germany'):
         return row['days_in_month']* 10
    if (row['Country'] == 'Conus'):
        return row['working_days']* 8
    else:
        return row['working_days']*8
forecast ['hours']= forecast.apply(lambda row: get_hours(row), axis=1)
print(forecast.head())

```
       Name      EID  Start Date   End Date      Country  year  Month  \
```

0            XX.    123456 2019-08-01 2020-01-03  Afghanistan  2020      1
1            xx    3456789 2019-09-22 2020-02-16        Conus  2020      1
2            Mh     456789 2019-12-05 2020-03-12        Conus  2020      1
3            DR     789456 2019-09-11 2020-03-04         Iraq  2020      1
4            JR     985756 2020-01-03 2020-05-06      Germany  2020      1

days_in_month start_month  end_month  working_days  conus_mth  oconus_mth  \
0             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          8           1
1             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          9           2
2             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21         12           3
3             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          9           3
4             31  2020-01-01 2020-01-31            21          1           5

conus_days  conus_days1  oconus_days  oconus_days1  hours
0           0            0            2            25    224
1           0            0            0             0    168
2           0            0            0             0    168
3           0            0            0             0    372
4           1           28            0             0    288  ​